# Adding single hidden input value to each form input in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a form with a button that can add dynamic input fields, and it's creating an ajax issue. My ajax post is giving me 500 errors
 But My console log for data right now is this:
[image]

but I need to insert these as

```
insert into ticker_content (ticker_id, content)
     values (1, 'one'), (1, 'two');
```

If that makes sense.

So basically, the problem is i have multiple inputs at any given time (containing text values) and a hidden input in the form that gives me my correct ticker ID.

However, I need to make my array contain elements that each have the input text value and the ticker ID. So for every input that's created and filled, I need to assign the value of that form's hidden input to it as well so I can sent them as pairs to my foreach loop and insert.

Here's my addticker.php that's being called for the insert:

```
$items = $_POST['Items'];
$tickerID = $_POST['tickerID'];

foreach ($items as $item){

    $addTicker = "
        INSERT INTO ticker_content (tickerID, content)
        values ('$tickerID', '$item');
     "
     $mysqlConn->query($addTicker);
}
```

So basically for every Items[] value, I need to insert with the same hidden field.

Here's my form and JS code for reference. The first JS block is mainly for the functionality of dynamically adding inputs, but the last JS block is the ajax using serializeArray();

```
<?php foreach($tickerDisplays as $key => $ticker):?>

    <form id="Items" method="post">   
        <label id="ItemLabel">Item 1: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Items[]"><br/> <!--form starts with one input-->
        <button type="button" class="moreItems_add">+</button> <!--button dynamically adds input, up to 10 per form-->

        <input type="hidden" name="tickerID" id="tickerID" class="tickerIdClass" value="<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>"><!--hidden input used for tickerID-->
        <input type="submit" name="saveTickerItems" value="Save Ticker Items">  <!--submit button-->
    </form>

<?php endforeach;?>




<!-- This is the functionality for each form to click the '+' button and create new inputs -->
<script type="text/javascript">

$("button.moreItems_add").on("click", function(e) {
var tickerID = $(this).closest('form').find('.tickerIdClass').val(); //get value of hidden input for form
  var numItems = $("input[type='text']", $(this).closest("form")).length;
  if (numItems < 10) {
    var html = '<label class="ItemLabel">Item ' + (numItems + 1) + ': </label>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="Items[]"/><br/>';
    $(this).before(html);
    console.log(tickerID);
  }
});

</script>

<!-- This is the ajax call to send all filled out and created inputs from form along with the hidden input -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Items").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#Items").serializeArray();
    console.log(data);

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "addticker.php",
       data: $("#Items").serializeArray(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

});

</script>
```

Comment: You `addticker.php` returns an error 500, which means: "Internal Server Error", usually due to an syntax error in PHP. I see a missing semi-column at the end of your query string. When you get an error 500 you can usually see what problem is in the PHP error log. Have you been warned about SQL-injection? Your code is vulnerable.

Comment: Ok, good catch. I added the semicolon and got a 200 that time but no insert. Is there a better way I can test this for results on the page or in the console? I just feel like it won't insert the way I expect, especially with  multiple inputs

Comment: As for the debugging after you've added the semi-column, you can use the developer tools of your browser. See: https://www.browserstack.com/developer-tools Go to the 'network' tab and check the parameters and output to see what your ajax call did. For debugging purposes you might want to echo something in your `addticker.php` to tell yourself what is happening.

Comment: On it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing a semicolon in your code (which is likely causing your 500 error).

Secondly, if you want to bundle all the fields from the form as a single query, the following will build out a query similar to what you noted earlier in your question as:

> **INSERT INTO ticker_content (ticker_id, content) VALUES(1, 'one'), (1, 'two'), ...**

```
$items = $_POST['Items'];
$tickerID = $_POST['tickerID'];

$addTicker = "INSERT INTO ticker_content (tickerID, content) values";
foreach ($items as $item){
    $addTicker .= "('$tickerID', '$item'),";
}
$addTicker = substr($addTicker, 0, -1); // Eat that last comma

$mysqlConn->query($addTicker);
```

Your HTML also needs some work because the `id` attribute should be unique on the page. Since you are duplicating the form, you should do something like the following:

```
<form id="Items<?php echo $ticker['ticker']?>" class="tickerform" method="post">
```

And then update your javascript:

```
// Using $(this) in Jquery allows you to access the 
// element that is making the method call (in this case, the form)
$(".tickerform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray(); 
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "addticker.php",
       data: data, // Don't need to serialize again, 'var data' is still in scope.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok so I actually got it to work with multiple fields on the same form! It inserted one record for each with the right ID. HOwever, the other forms have a submit button as well that doesn't work (probably due to an id on the submit input in my form?) Can you help me out there? So that no matter how many forms, the functionality will be the same?

Comment: So basically, submitting the first form works fine functionally but I may need a count or something on the submit button so that it will work on each form

Comment: @Whisou138 Updated answer.

Comment: You're the best! Thank you